# Consumir .jar em projeto java web

Tags: java, java-ee, aplicação-web, jsp

Criei um arquivo .jar (script.jar) que contém o método "imprimir()" apenas retorna uma string e gostaria que quando eu clicasse um botão na minha aplicação Java Web (JavaEE) esse método "imprimir()" fosse executado.

Método do arquivo script.jar

```
package jardeteste.metodos;

public class Test{
     public static String imprimir(){
          return "Teste de Impressão";
     }
}
```

Método bean que recebe e manipula o click (checkBoxView.java)

```
package projetojavaweb.bean;

import jardeteste.metodos;

@ManagedBean
public class CheckboxView {

        public static void executar(ActionEvent event) {
                String recebedor = Teste.imprimir();
                System.out.println(recebedor);
        }

}
```

View caso seja necessário: (testList.xhtml)

```
 <p:commandButton value="Printar" actionListener="#{checkboxView.executar}" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
```

Erro que gera no log:

```
WARNING: /pages/testList.xhtml @20,124 actionListener="#{checkboxView.listarTestes}": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jardeteste.metodos
    javax.el.ELException: /pages/testList.xhtml @20,124 actionListener="#{checkboxView.listarTestes}": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jardeteste/metodos
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
        at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
        at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Você deve importar a sua classe java no seu classpath ou gerenciar a sua dependência diretamente pelo maven.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve definir uma classe ou importar todo o pacote no import:

```
import jardeteste.metodos.*;
```

ou

```
import jardeteste.metodos.Teste;
```

Você também pode importar diretamente os componentes estáticos da classe Teste:

```
import static jardeteste.metodos.Teste.*;
```

Desta forma não precisa colocar a classe durante a chamada do método:

```
String recebedor = imprimir();
```